# How can I validate some dynamic field in child component Blazor From Parent?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a Blazor `EditForm` with multiple fields but I used dynamic combo box in child component.

How can I validate a Combo box in child component while EditForm tag in parent component?

[image: 1]

Comment: I would recommend posting your code if possible, it makes it much easier for contributors to help answer your question more directly

Comment: [Fluent Validations](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html) can do that. Chris Sainty has a [Blazor component](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation) that simplifies it. Good info on validation in his book as well.

Comment: If Fluent Validations doesn't answer your question you will need to post some code to show us some detail on your dynamic xxx component and validation process.